# Laravel price range search from multiple columns

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have to search price range(min_price & max_price) from two columns(regular_price & sale_price) but unable to get values from both columns.

Comment: what did you try? and what didn't work?

Comment: i tried all available queries whereBetween, whereRaw and some other as suggested but didn't work well.

Comment: $products = $products->whereBetween('ecommerce_sku.regular_price', [$minPrice, $maxPrice]);

i'm using this one but this one only get products from one column  not from both if i add one another column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search with 'and' logic you can chain `whereBetween` method likt this:

```php
$query->whereBetween('regular_price', [$min_price, $max_price])
    ->whereBetween('sale_price', [$min_price, $max_price]);
```

Or you can use orWhereBetween` method:

```php
$query->where(function($q){
    return $q->whereBetween('regular_price', [$min_price, $max_price])
        ->orWhereBetween('sale_price', [$min_price, $max_price]);
});
```